# Spark ORC reader is reading complete file even though single column is queried

Tags: apache-spark, orc

We are building a solution using spark 1.6.1 where we need to read an ORC file and execute business logic on it. Spark documentation about reading an ORC file says that ***The columnar format lets the reader read, decompress, and process only the columns that are required for the current query.*** But in our case, even though SQL query selects only one column, the SparkUI shows that whole file is getting read.

I found similar question about parquet format here -> [While Reading a specific Parquet Column , All column are read instead of single column which is given in Parquet-Sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37183774/while-reading-a-specific-parquet-column-all-column-are-read-instead-of-single). But it is not solved.

**Sample code**

ORC file has been created as follows:

```
lines = sc.textFile("file:///home/user/data/testdata.csv")
parts = lines.map(lambda l: l.split(","))
people = parts.map(lambda p: Row(id=int(p[0]),fname=p[1],mname=p[2],lname=p[3],address=p[4],marks=p[5],grade=p[6],age=p[7],experience=p[8]))
people.toDF().write.format("orc").save("/home/user/orcdata/people5m")
```

And it is read as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext, Row
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
people = sqlContext.read.format("orc").load("/home/user/orcdata/people5m")
people.registerTempTable("people")
addresses = sqlContext.sql("SELECT 'address' FROM people")
addresses.count()
```

The size of ORC data on HDFS is 91.6 M and on SparkUI, the same number '91.6 M' is shown in ***Input*** column on the ***stages*** tab. Is there anything wrong with this code? Can somebody explain this behavior?

[Spark UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58aDZ.png)

Comment: Can you try enabling predicate and projection pushdown?